# Android YouTubeAPi Video not playing when opened second time

Tags: android, video, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play YouTube videos in android app.
For the first time when i open the activity the video plays fine.
When i press back and come again with different videoId the video is not played at all buffering never happens

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.orhanobut.logger.Logger;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {


    private String videoId;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment;
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initValues();
    }

    private void initValues() {
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            videoId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoId");
            youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.YOU_TUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
            youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
            youTubePlayer.play();
            Logger.w("Running");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        Logger.e("Errrrrrrrrr");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
            Logger.e("Error: " + arg0.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
            Logger.e("Loaded: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            Logger.e("Loaded:ing");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            Logger.e("Ended");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            Logger.e("Started");
        }
    };


    private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
            Logger.w("Buffereuibng: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            Logger.w("Pauseed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            Logger.w("Playing");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            Logger.w("Stopped");
        }

    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.youTubePlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

After running second time i am getting this log

```
10-21 13:39:57.853 31623-31623/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
10-21 13:39:57.857 29691-29691/? V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
10-21 13:39:57.861 1072-10335/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
10-21 13:39:57.867 29691-7678/? E/AudioAttributes: Invalid stream type -2147483648 for AudioAttributes
10-21 13:39:57.868 1072-1651/? I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@ec4bb20kyu@365515b2 req=1flags=0x0
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kab.a(SourceFile:792)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.g(SourceFile:554)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kae.g(SourceFile:146)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.e(SourceFile:1083)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.w(SourceFile:1073)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyr.j(SourceFile:477)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyr.a(SourceFile:4469)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyr.a(SourceFile:680)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at aha.a(SourceFile:267)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at aha.b(SourceFile:287)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at apq.run(SourceFile:209)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-21 13:39:57.868 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kab.a(SourceFile:792)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.g(SourceFile:554)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kae.g(SourceFile:146)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.c(SourceFile:488)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsf.b(SourceFile:245)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsm.b(SourceFile:148)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyr.a(SourceFile:694)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at aha.a(SourceFile:267)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at aha.b(SourceFile:287)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at apq.run(SourceFile:209)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-21 13:39:57.874 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kab.a(SourceFile:792)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.g(SourceFile:554)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kae.g(SourceFile:146)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.s(SourceFile:585)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.c(SourceFile:490)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsf.b(SourceFile:245)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsm.b(SourceFile:148)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyr.a(SourceFile:694)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at aha.a(SourceFile:267)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at aha.b(SourceFile:287)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at apq.run(SourceFile:209)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-21 13:39:57.875 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
10-21 13:39:57.944 1072-10333/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
10-21 13:39:58.105 1072-1103/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
10-21 13:39:58.109 1072-1103/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
10-21 13:39:58.122 1072-1103/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
10-21 13:39:58.145 1072-1743/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
10-21 13:39:58.343 29691-29691/? V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:false
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kab.a(SourceFile:792)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.b(SourceFile:317)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.a(SourceFile:300)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.a(SourceFile:209)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kae.a(SourceFile:52)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.J(SourceFile:939)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.d(SourceFile:848)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.I(SourceFile:813)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.a(SourceFile:18664)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsg.a(SourceFile:370)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lov.a(SourceFile:73)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsf.a(SourceFile:339)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsn.a(SourceFile:2326)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at gwo.a(SourceFile:33)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at ljq.run(SourceFile:297)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-21 13:39:58.346 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.b(SourceFile:6796)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.a(SourceFile:300)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.a(SourceFile:209)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kae.a(SourceFile:52)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.J(SourceFile:939)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.d(SourceFile:848)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.I(SourceFile:813)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.a(SourceFile:18664)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsg.a(SourceFile:370)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lov.a(SourceFile:73)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsf.a(SourceFile:339)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsn.a(SourceFile:2326)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at gwo.a(SourceFile:33)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at ljq.run(SourceFile:297)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-21 13:39:58.347 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {18ae5da4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:507)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.b(SourceFile:7776)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.a(SourceFile:300)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at jzw.a(SourceFile:209)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kae.a(SourceFile:52)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.J(SourceFile:939)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.d(SourceFile:848)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.I(SourceFile:813)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at kyi.a(SourceFile:18664)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsg.a(SourceFile:370)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lov.a(SourceFile:73)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsf.a(SourceFile:339)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at lsn.a(SourceFile:2326)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at gwo.a(SourceFile:33)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at ljq.run(SourceFile:297)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-21 13:39:58.350 29691-29691/? W/MessageQueue:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
10-21 13:39:58.372 1072-1091/? V/WindowManager: ** SHOWING status bar: top is not fullscreen
```

Comment: Are you seeing this log output when you resume? Logger.w("Running");

Comment: Yes for first time as well as second time, Running is also printed for first time started then buffering but for second time it stucks on Started only

Comment: Are you doing anything with `IntentService`s or `Handler`s when it comes to playing the video (e.g., fetching the videoId in the background?)

Comment: Thanks all its api key issue.

Comment: I'm facing this problem. Can you clarify the api key issue for me? Thanks.

Comment: @HuyDuongTu try resetting the keystore and getting new update SHA1 fingerprint and API key...

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't work. My problem is I play youtube video in fragment.  I remove this fragment, then add it again later. Now the video can not play. Buffering never happen.

Comment: @HuyDuongTu i assume it to be Keystore issue only did you enable youtube api in google console

Comment: yes. I can play video at the first time. If I use Activity instead of fragment, it's ok. There are some problems with fragment that is youtubeplayer is not released when fragment is destroyed.

Comment: @HuyDuongTu how are you adding fragment. When you leave the activity can you pop out fragment if in case you are adding it to backstack?

Comment: Thanks. I have to call youtubeplayer.release() before super.onDestroyedView() of Fragment. It's working now.